# Llenar parte de un formulario php/html de forma dinámica usando jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente formulario que he hecho usando Bootstrap.

El formulario tiene dos grupos de campos (aquí sólo muestro los campos del grupo 1).

```html
<form class="form-inline">
<!-- Grupo 1 del formulario, rellenarlo con el arreglo $arrOficio -->
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-xs-9">id_oficio</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_oficio" placeholder="id_oficio"/>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4">id_liturgia</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_liturgia" placeholder="id_liturgia"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_antifona</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_antifona" placeholder="ol_antifona"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_himno</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_himno" placeholder="ol_himno"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_salmos</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_salmos" placeholder="ol_salmos"/>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_responsorio</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_responsorio" placeholder="ol_responsorio"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_biblica</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_biblica" placeholder="ol_biblica"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_patristica</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_patristica" placeholder="ol_patristica"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_oracion</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_oracion" placeholder="ol_oracion"/>

     </div>
 </div>
<!-- Grupo 2 del formulario, rellenarlo con el arreglo $arrLaudes -->
</form>
```

Yo tomo de un `select` desde otra parte del formulario un `id` con el cual consulto a la Base de datos para obtener todos los elementos con los cuales quiero llenar de forma dinámica todos los `input` pertenecientes al grupo 1 de mi formulario.

La respuesta de la base de datos es un arreglo asociativo parecido a este, el cual yo almaceno en una variable llamada `$arrOficio`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_oficio] => 119
            [id_liturgia] => 15
            [ol_antifona] => 0600000001
            [ol_himno] => 0601000101
            [ol_salmos] => 0600040101
            [ol_responsorio] => 0602000101
            [ol_biblica] => 0607040101
            [ol_patristica] => 0607040101
            [ol_oracion] => 0600040100
        )

)
```

Como ven, he dado a cada `id`del formulario el mismo nombre que tienen los nombres de columnas de mi tabla en la Base de datos.

Lo que quisiera saber es, **¿cuál sería la mejor forma de pasar mi variable `$arrOficio` a jQuery para que me llene de forma dinámica los diferentes `input` del formulario?**

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que quieres hacer algo así, asumo que estas usando ajax

```js
let response = [
       {
            'id_oficio': 119,
            'id_liturgia': 15,
            'ol_antifona': 0600000001,
            'ol_himno': 0601000101,
            'ol_salmos': 0600040101,
            'ol_responsorio': 0602000101,
            'ol_biblica': 0607040101,
            'ol_patristica': 0607040101,
            'ol_oracion': 0600040100
        }
]

response.map(row => {
  for(let key in row){
    document.getElementById(key).value = row[key]
  }
})
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
<!-- Grupo 1 del formulario, rellenarlo con el arreglo $arrOficio -->
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-xs-9">id_oficio</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_oficio" placeholder="id_oficio"/>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4">id_liturgia</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_liturgia" placeholder="id_liturgia"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_antifona</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_antifona" placeholder="ol_antifona"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_himno</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_himno" placeholder="ol_himno"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_salmos</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_salmos" placeholder="ol_salmos"/>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_responsorio</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_responsorio" placeholder="ol_responsorio"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_biblica</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_biblica" placeholder="ol_biblica"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_patristica</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_patristica" placeholder="ol_patristica"/>
         <label class="col-md-4">ol_oracion</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ol_oracion" placeholder="ol_oracion"/>

     </div>
 </div>
<!-- Grupo 2 del formulario, rellenarlo con el arreglo $arrLaudes -->
</form>
```